# Search in multidimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search, multidimensional-array

I has multidimensional array of

```
int[,] PDATVL = new int[100,2];
```

Let dummy data be:

```
249 398
249 423
249 448
249 473
249 498
251 17
251 42
251 325
252 142
252 418
253 194
254 7
254 319
255 81
255 378
```

Now I want to search for 251, 142 pair in the array.
What will be the best approach for this except linear search.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The array contains integers; how can we look for a pair?

Comment: what is wrong with linear search?

Comment: Is the array always sorted in lexical order?

Comment: Are the contents somehow sorted? If not, you can't do better than linear search.

Comment: @Erno: there are two columns of ints, each row representing a pair of ints.

Comment: @Matt Ellen, ah yes, so we are looking for a row, not a pair... OK. If it is not sorted in any way linear is the only way.

Comment: Do you have `System.Data.DataRow`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with pairs why not use the structure

```
HashSet<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
```

or

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
```

if not in .NET 4.

Then you can search a pair like this:

```
pairs.Where(p=> p.Key == 251 && p.Value == 142);
```

Comment: `HashSet<T>` is already avaiable in .NET 3.5. And if you use a hashset, you should use the `Contains()` method (O(1)) instead of `Where()` (O(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Given that the array is sorted in lexical order, you have two options:

1. Write a custom binary search method that works with a two-dimensional array.
2. Write a struct that stores a pair of integers and implements `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`

I would go for option two. A basic implementation for such a struct would be:

```
public struct Pair : IComparable<Pair>, IEquatable<Pair>
{
    private readonly int x;
    private readonly int y;

    public Pair(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int Y { get { return y; } }

    public int CompareTo(Pair other)
    {
        return (x == other.x) ? y.CompareTo(other.y) : x.CompareTo(other.x);
    }

    public bool Equals(Pair other)
    {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `Array.BinarySearch` method:

```
var pairs = new[] {new Pair(1, 1), new Pair(1,2), new Pair(1, 3), new Pair(2, 3), new Pair(2, 4)};

// Returns 2
int index1 = Array.BinarySearch(pairs, new Pair(1,3));

// No match. Returns a negative number.
int index2 = Array.BinarySearch(pairs, new Pair(1, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted, then you can use binary search.

The built in method `Array.BinarySearch` only handles one-dimensional arrays, so you have to implement it yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a maximum value of each of the values in the pair, then you could combine them into a single value, like so:

```
long pair = value1 * 10000000 + value2; // assuming value2 < 1000000
```

and then store them in a Dictionary (or HashSet in .NET 4), so that searching is O(1):

```
var d = new Dictionary<long, object>;
long pair1 = 251 * 1000000 + 142;
d.Add(pair1, null);
long pair 2 = ....
// ...

var exists = d.ContainsKey(pair1);
```